# "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError" when trying to read Redshift External Tables using Dask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, dask

I am able to read all other tables using Dask from Redshift. But when trying to read External Tables, I am getting this error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError`. Although that particular table is accessible using Pandas.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
conn = 'redshift+psycopg2://username:password@cluster.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db_name'
df = dd.read_sql_table("table_name", conn, schema="schema_name", index_col="index_key")
print(df)
```

I am able to read using Pandas like this.

```
engine = create_engine(conn)
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df = pd.read_sql("""select * from schema.table_name;""", conn)
print(df)
```

I read many articles. I think there is something wrong with `sqlalchemy` library. Can someone please help me out in this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This issue is only while reading external schemas

Comment: Please confirm: if you do pd.read_sql_ptable and the same table/conn/schema, it works?

Comment: @mdurant, No, it doesn't work. I am able to run like this using Pandas.

   `engine = create_engine(conn) with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin(): df = pd.read_sql("""select * from schema.table_name;""", conn)`

Comment: You could try dropping the schema keyword and use the long-form table name.

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: Please share your traceback

Comment: looks like external table support is still an open issue for sqlalchemy-redshift? https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/issues/122